# Pass an string representing an object function as callback

Tags: javascript

This code doesn't work:

```js
var my = {
  testFunction: function(text) {
    alert(text);
  }
};

var functionName = "my.testFunction";

var f = window[functionName];

f('yeha');
```

Any idea why?

Update:

I don't know in advance the functionName. It might be 'my.testFunction' or 'my.test.another.function' etc.

I'm writing a validation handler and all my js will know is a string representing a function that could be a function inside an object.

Comment: Do you have a variable named `"my.testFunction"`?

Comment: `eval(functionName + '()')` makes it work. It doesn't now because bracket notation can be used to access only a direct property of an object.

Comment: Vote to close as a question without clear problem statement. posts seeking debug help like Why this code isn't working is off topic here

Comment: The question is: why do you expect using dots in property name in brackets would magically access nested object's property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
var my = {
    testFunction: function(text) {
        alert(text);
    }
};

// the string can't be evaluated as nested object hierarchy.
// split it to address the several nodes and properties
var functionName = "my.testFunction".split('.');

var f = window[functionName[0]][functionName[1]];

f('yeha');
```

Comment: code explanation

Comment: Question is not about how to fix. Its about WHY its not working

Comment: `my.testFunction` is not present in window. You will get your object with `window['my']`. So `window['my'].testFunction` will work

Comment: Added the comment

Comment: Sory for not being clear enough ... I don't know the functionName in advance. It might be 'my.testFunction' or 'my.test.another.function' etc.

Comment: Yes, you have to split the path to the function within the object hierarchy by a delimiter. My simple solution can be refactored to a for loop, allowing any depth and path.

Comment: Florian ... thanks I will figure out the loop. :)